# swift 3: how to bypass the textFieldShouldEndEditing func when Back navigation button is clicked

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I've implemented the textFieldShouldEndEditing function to validate the data entered into each field before the user exits the field.  If the entered data does not pass the validation, it does not allow the user to exit the field.

However, while this works fine, the problem I'm running into is that it's being triggered when the user clicks the Back navigation button.  For whatever reason, when this happens, the prior view controller is presented.  If I then go back into the view controller, the fields are not editable at all.  No keyboard is presented, the cursor does not go into the field, nothing.

My question is how do I either bypass the textFieldShouldEndEditing function when the user clicks the Back button OR how can I detect that the Back button was clicked in my validation functions, so I can return true and get past this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my textFieldShouldEndEditing func (the validation funcs called return either true or false):

```
internal func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (tField.isEditing) {
        return tFieldValidated()
    } else if (oField.isEditing) {
        return oFieldValidated()
    } else {
        return distanceFieldValidated()
    }
 }
```

This is in swift 3 and Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  Here's what I had to do:

1 - I created a global boolean boolCancelled and set it to false.  This is used to flag whether the Cancel button was clicked or not.

2 - Override the Back button on the nav bar.  To do this, I added the following code in the viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(RaceDetailVCClass.backButtonAction))
```

3 - I also created a backButtonAction function:

```
func backButtonAction(){
    // set the boolean to True to indicate the Cancel button was clicked
    boolCancelled = true
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

4 - Defaulted the boolCancelled to false in viewDidLoad()

5 - Added a check for boolCancelled in the textFieldShouldEndEditing function:

```
internal func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (boolCancelled) {
        return true
    } else if (tField.isEditing) {
        return tFieldValidated()
    } else if (oField.isEditing) {
        return oFieldValidated()
    } else {
        return distanceFieldValidated()
    }
}
```

Now when I click the Cancel button, the textFieldShouldEndEditing will return true and everything works as I need it to work.

Comment: what if the user goes back with a swipe?